# Thinking Sphinx getting facet names of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a Rails app, and I need the facet names of a certain model. Is there a method to get all the facet names defined?

Also it would be helpful to know the index names.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by facet names?  Are you referring to the ASP concept?

Comment: when you add a new facet you could pass an :as option like this:

has properties.map(&:rooms_from).range_to_sql('rooms'), :type => :integer, :as => :rooms_range, :facet => true

Like that you could refer to this facet as "rooms_range"

Comment: BTW sorry, I didn't figure it out yet how to format comments

Comment: Sorry as well, I didnt see you were refering to thinking sphynx.  Unfortunately not very experienced with it